# How to create the tree in the Huffman Tree program?

Tags: c++, tree

I am trying to create the Huffman Tree in c++. I have gotten as far as creatig the priority queue with the individual characters (read from a txt file) and now I am stuck at creating the actual tree. First of all, I know what needs to be done. I have to dequeue the first two items from the queue and then use those to make a tree and then enqueue the tree back into the queue. But how am I supposed to implement that?

Comment: Huffman will allways result in an binary tree, so the easiest way is first of all write yourself an binary-tree-class [like that](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html) and then fill the data structure with your values.

Comment: Yes I know that, but that isnt the problem that I am facing, I need to know how to enqueue a pointer into an array of struct node